# Unable to make video and audio calls with Pidgin (Skype)

Tags: sound, skype, webcam, pidgin, pidgin-sipe

I'm using Pidgin to communicate with my colleagues through Skype (yeah, I know, Skype... right)

Thing is, I seem to be unable to make video calls
**debug log**:

`(15:58:16) mediamanager: gst pipeline error: Internal data stream error.
(15:58:16) mediamanager: Debug details: gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstBin:pidgindefaultvideosrc/GstBin:pidgindefaultvideosrc/GstAutoVideoSrc:autovideosrc3/GstV4l2Src:autovideosrc3-actual-src-v4l:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
(15:58:16) backend-fs2: gst error Internal data stream error.
debugging: gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstBin:pidgindefaultvideosrc/GstBin:pidgindefaultvideosrc/GstAutoVideoSrc:autovideosrc3/GstV4l2Src:autovideosrc3-actual-src-v4l:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
(15:58:16) media: Error with your webcam
(15:58:16) media: Conference error`

or even audio calls as I get an "Unable to establish a call 488 Not acceptable here" error

Running Ubuntu 18.04.1 (64bit)
Pidgin from repo > 2.12

Webcam and sound work perfectly well on Wire or Cheese...

Any suggestions ?

**UPDATE 2018-09-04**

So came across this PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~sipe-collab/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Updated pidgin-sipe and some gstream packages
Now the audio calls are working... nice

But no luck with video conferences yet...
Still getting:

```
(15:36:08) mediamanager: gst pipeline error: Internal data stream error.
(15:36:08) mediamanager: Debug details: gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstBin:vvconfig-videosrc/GstBin:pidgindefaultvideosrc/GstAutoVideoSrc:autovideosrc1/GstV4l2Src:autovideosrc1-actual-src-v4l:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
(15:36:08) backend-fs2: gst error Internal data stream error.
debugging: gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstBin:vvconfig-videosrc/GstBin:pidgindefaultvideosrc/GstAutoVideoSrc:autovideosrc1/GstV4l2Src:autovideosrc1-actual-src-v4l:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
(15:36:08) media: Error with your webcam
```

Comment: nobody ? This is really painful... I figure it has got something to do with gstreamer... But this is way out of my league

Comment: As far as I know you need the skype client installed as well as pidgin. Pidgin then uses the so's containing the closed protocol from skype and the encryption that way. I think I once had chat working from pidgin on skype. Never the camera / mic.

Comment: I don't think so... Skype for Business has nothing to do with Skype... It's Lync really... A complete different protocol